# Dynamic additions of DIVS

Tags: html, css

I am attempting dynamically add child divs which would automatically resize their parent divs but my CSS doesn't render them properly. Code below

HTML

```
<head>
        <title>Dealer Services Hub</title>    
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper"> 
            <div id="header">
             </div>
            </div>

            <div id="body">

                <div id = "maindiv">
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Sales/Credit</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Finance</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Compliance/Audit</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Admin</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Reporting</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>EOT</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Test</div>

                </div>

                <div id = "sidebardiv">

                     <div class = 'sidebardivs' div id = 'recentsdiv'><div id = 'recentlinkstitle'>Frequent Views</div></div>
                  <div class = 'sidebardivs' div id ='dealercommentsdiv'>Dealer Comments</div>
                  <div class = 'sidebardivs'>Dealers</div>                    

                </div>

            </div>

    <!--Footer Div-->
         <div id="footer">
             <div>
                 <span>USBNet</span>
             </div>

             <div>
                <span>Best In Us</span>
             </div>

             <div>
                <span>Directory</span>
             </div>


         </div>

        </div>



</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    color:#0C2074;
}

h2{
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}

#wrapper {
    width:1400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto; 
}

#header{
    width: 1320px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: #0C2074;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#maindiv{
    width:1000px;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    color:#0C2074;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.maindivs{
    width:300px;
    height: 220px;
    background: #67B2E8;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px #888888;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px; 
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color:#0C2074;
}


#sidebardiv{
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #5a5a5a;
    overflow:hidden;  
}


.sidebardivs{
    width:90%;
    height: 220px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    color:#0C2074;
    margin-top: 20px; 
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#recentsdiv{
    font-size: 95%;    
}

#dealercommentsdiv{
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#footer{
    width: 1320px;
    height:40px;
    float: left;
    background: #0C2074;
    clear: both;
    color:#FFF;
}

#footer div{
    width:33.33%;
    height: 100%;  
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #67B2E8;
    border-right: 1px solid #67B2E8;
    font-size: 120%;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
}
```

The additional div is 'Test' for the parent 'maindiv' and 'Dealers' to the parent 'sidediv' The result is the 'Test' div seems to be cut off at its base and the space between the 'Dealers' div is more than necessary

Comment: I don't see what's dynamic about this. Also you can't repeat IDs -- they must be unique

Comment: I mentioned dynamic because this is the basis of an ASP project I'm building. The divs are built based on DB structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it better now?:

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    color:#0C2074;
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto; 
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: #0C2074;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#maindiv{
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    color:#0C2074;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.maindivs{
    width:30%;
    height: 210px;
    background: #67B2E8;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 8px #666;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px; 
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color:#0C2074;
}


#sidebardiv{
    width:19%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #5a5a5a;
    overflow:hidden;  
}


.sidebardivs{
    width:80%;
    height: 210px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    color:#0C2074;
    margin-top: 30px; 
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-align:center;
}

#recentsdiv{
    font-size: 95%;    
}

#dealercommentsdiv{
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;
    background: #0C2074;
    clear: both;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
}

#footer div{
    width:30%;
   height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    border-left: 1px solid #67B2E8;
    border-right: 1px solid #67B2E8;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Dealer Services Hub</title>    
</head>    
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper"> 
        <div id="header">
        </div>
            </div>

            <div id="body">

                <div id="maindiv">
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Sales/Credit</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Finance</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Compliance/Audit</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Admin</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Reporting</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>EOT</div>
                    <div class = 'maindivs'>Test</div>

                </div>

                <div id = "sidebardiv">

                  <div class ='sidebardivs' id = 'recentsdiv'><div id = 'recentlinkstitle'>Frequent Views</div></div>
                  <div class ='sidebardivs' id ='dealercommentsdiv'>Dealer Comments</div>
                  <div class = 'sidebardivs'>Dealers</div>                    

                </div>

            </div>

    <!--Footer Div-->
         <div id="footer">
             <div>
                 <span>USBNet</span>
             </div>

             <div>
                <span>Best In Us</span>
             </div>

             <div>
                <span>Directory</span>
             </div>


         </div>

        </div>



</body>
```